# Android - DownloadManager replace file with the same path

Tags: android, file, path, android-download-manager

Is it possible to replace the downloaded file if it has the same name?

Right now the DM is creating file a.txt, and then a-1.txt and so on. Sometimes I will need to update the downloaded file.

The only way that I see seems to be to check and delete the file before the download begins, but this will leave the application without file while the file is being downloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to replace the downloaded file if it has the same name?

No because of:

[public static final int ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS)

> The only way that I see seems to be to check and delete the file
>   before the download begins, but this will leave the application
>   without file while the file is being downloaded.

move your file to a temp folder and set download manager destination to original folder.

Comment: thank you, sound as a better solution, any change you have a piece of code for moving the file?

Comment: I do not have right now but quick search will give you lots of code:-)